# Matching contours and smoothing them using OpenCV, EmguCV or other alternative library

Tags: c#, python, c++, opencv, emgucv

I am a beginner using OpenCV and EmguCV. I am having two issues finding contours (see picture below). Problem A is about how the different contours match with each other. Problem B is about how to obtain smoother contours.

[image]

To detect the contours I am using:

FindContours(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_LIST);

Can someone give some advice on this?

Many thanks!!

Comment: So you want it 4-connected instead of 8-connected?

Comment: Exactly! I need to get simple connections between the contours.

Answer (score 0):

[Skeletonization](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/skeleton.htm) is the solution to your first problem. Take note there are a few flavors of skeletonization, so if the one you try doesn't produce the desired output, try with another one.

For problem B, it is impossible to make the contour smoother without upscaling the image (increasing its size artificially). As for making the contours continuous in 4-connectedness (so diagonals do not count), you can modify the chain codes of the found contours.

> CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE stores absolutely all the contour points. That
>   is, any 2 subsequent points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) of the contour will be
>   either horizontal, vertical or **diagonal neighbors**, that is,
>   max(abs(x1-x2),abs(y2-y1))==1.

For each contour, go through its chain code array. If you encounter a diagonal change in coordinates between two subsequent points, insert a new point in the chain code array that will "fill the diagonal" to your liking. For example:

```
    xxx                    becomes     xxxx          or   xxx
       xxx                                xxx               xxxx
```

Comment: Thanks Boyko! How would you proceed acceding the contours and so on?  Can you give me a flavour of the code? Sorry if the question is somehow basic but as  I said I am a complete beginner.

Comment: I can't help you with real code - it's been a while since I've used emgucv. Best of luck!